# Where is the chat?

Tags: support, chat

I don't know if someone asked this (I checked and it seems not so) and I just noticed that the chat button is no longer there.

There is this "Blog" button instead with the "new" badge next to it.

So... where is the chat?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101464/eeeek-where-did-the-chat-top-navigation-link-go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chat link is still found in all other points - it can be found in the site footer, and on the Meta front page you'll always see a set of active rooms in the right sidebar that can be clicked on to access chat.

The chat link will also continue to be on the header, *however*, there is some new functionality. To help with the visibility of our per-site blogs for those sites that have them, the header will now show a link to the blog to logged-in users for the first 24 hours after any new post. To make room for it, the chat link was subtracted for logged-in users during those 24 hours. After that time passes, the top link to chat will return.

In the case of English, all sites which do not have their own blog instead point at the general Stack Exchange blog, which in this case has recently had a new post on the changes to our tag system.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd accept your answer, but it won't let me to yet. +1 anyway :) Honestly I didn't think of the room links in the main site, I should have. But you added info anyway :D Correct me if I'm wrong, but you said that the chat button will be back: does it mean it will co-exist with the Blog button or this last one will disappear?

Comment: @Alenanno The blog link will vanish when the chat link is back.

Comment: So when is the ELU specific blog coming?

Comment: @Mitch Do you guys want one? I noticed [some steam behind the idea](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1426/call-for-blog-participation) from a couple months ago, if that steam is still strong then it may be time to look into that.

Comment: @Grace: That's exactly the steam I'm thinking of. I think there was great interest, but nothing has happened since because...well..how -do- we create/administer an ELU blog? Do our moderators do that? Anyway..see the list of dedicated posters and topics already in answers at that question.

Comment: @Mitch I'll run over the process and see what can be done about that, then, and report when I've got word for better or for worse. ♪